# Endpoint Returning 404 from Pytest

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, pytest

I have an API that I am working on building the test_app.py file for, but it already works entirely and has been tested via Postman both locally & hosted externally.

I can't get even my health endpoint to work, which is keeping me (obviously) from making any more tests and moving forward. It's not failing the test, though, it's kicking back 404 when I print the variable I assign to the endpoint.

test_app.py:

```
import os
import unittest
import json
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from app import create_app
from models import setup_db, Actor, Movie

class CastingAgencyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app()
        self.client = self.app.test_client
        self.database_name = "casting_test"
        self.database_path = "postgres://{}/{}".format("localhost:5432", self.database_name)
        setup_db(self.app, self.database_path)

        self.new_actor = {
            "name": "Robert DOwney Jr.",
            "age": 45,
            "gender": "male"
        }

        self.new_movie = {
            "title": "Iron Man",
            "release_date": "02/03/2004"
        }
        with self.app.app_context():
            self.db = SQLAlchemy()
            self.db.init_app(self.app)
            self.db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_health(self):
        res = self.client().get('/')
        print(res)
        data = json.loads(res.data)

        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
        self.assertIn('health', data)
        self.assertEqual(data['health'], 'App is running.')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

The output of that `print(res)` is `<Response streamed [404 NOT FOUND]>`, and then the test fails because there is nothing in res.data, but of course not because the page isn't found.

app.py (up to where the health endpoint is created):

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, abort, jsonify, render_template, \
    redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_cors import CORS
from models import Actor, Movie, setup_db, db_drop_and_create_all, db
from auth import AuthError, requires_auth


def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    setup_db(app)
    CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

    # db_drop_and_create_all()

    return app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug=True)

# -----------
# @app.routes
# -----------


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
                         'Content-Type, Authorization')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
                         'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
    return response


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return jsonify({
        'success': True,
        'health': 'App is running.'
    }), 200
```

models.py (to the point where setup_db is created):

```
import os
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, ForeignKey, Float, Date, Table
from flask_migrate import Migrate

# ---------
# Config.
# ---------

database_path = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
if not database_path:
    database_name = "agency"
    database_path = "postgres://{}:{}@{}/{}".format(
        'postgres', 'root', 'localhost:5000', database_name)

db = SQLAlchemy()


def setup_db(app, database_path=database_path):
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = database_path
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
    db.app = app
    db.init_app(app)
```

After finding some videos regarding this kind of testing, I can't figure out why the page might kick back 404.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found.

It was that all of my endpoints (really, just the entire app.py file) needed to be within the create_app function, and at the end of the file is where app = create_app is called.